# Firebase: During testing I get "undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

This is my used code:

```
var cred = firebase.auth().EmailAuthProvider($scope.data.mail, $scope.data.pwd);

firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(cred)
                                        .then(function()
```

During testing, I get the following error:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating
>   'firebase.auth().EmailAuthProvider($scope.data.mail,
>   $scope.data.pwd)')

So what's wrong with my code? How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To log a user in via email/pass you just call the `signInWithEmailAndPassword` method.

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // ...
});
```

Then you can listen for the realtime auth event:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user !== null) {
    console.log('logged in!');
  }
});
```

[**Check the docs here for more on email login.**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#sign_in_a_user_with_an_email_address_and_password)

[**Check the API reference for onAuthStateChanged for more info.**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onAuthStateChanged)

Comment: You're passing in the user as an object. It's two separate parameters `email` and `password`, look at my first code sample.

Comment: That solved the problem, thanks so much. But the auth event gets trigerred many times: so why?

Comment: It's a realtime auth event. It fires for each state change. It fires when there is no one logged in and the `user` param is null. It also fires when the user has logged in and the `user` param is the populated user. That's why the if statement is in the callback.

Comment: But in my case, the event still occurs even if the `user` is not null.

Comment: Yes, and that is what you want. When `user` is not null it indicates that the logged in event has been successful and you have the currently authenticated user.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't very clear in my explanation. But, I did the test using the following code: `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user)
                                {
                                    if (user)
                                        if (user.emailVerified)
                                            $state.go('home');
                                        else
                                        {
                                            alert("hi");return;`
I'm getting the alert "hi" many times, though nothing else happens at that time.

Comment: Your if statement is invalid. So it will always fire the alert. Always use brackets. Also we are diverging away from the original question right now.

Comment: That's not true. My 'if' statements are valid. I'm still receiving the alert twice. I still need some help.

Comment: The if statement your provided will not compile. Can you update your code in the question, not in the comments?

Comment: I had updated a lot of stuff on my code, so I think there were maybe some bugs which caused that. All works fine now. Anyway, I would like to thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed By:

```
const register = () => {
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((auth) => {
        setPass(1);
      })
      .catch((error) => alert(error.message));
  };

  console.log(pass);

  if (pass === 1) {
    updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {
      displayName: name,
      photoURL: image || "https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg",
    })
      .then(() => {
        // Profile updated!
        // ...
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // An error occurred
        // ...
      });

    setPass(0);
  }
```